# Can i run stored procedure in spark pool synapse?

Tags: azure, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse, spark-notebook

I wanted to know how we can run stored procedure in spark pool (azure synapse) which i have created in dedicated SQL pool. Also can we run SQL queries to access data in ddsql pool in notebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to do this (eg using an ODBC connection as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67525469/1527504)) but you would be better off just using a Synapse Pipeline to do the orchestration:

1. run a stored Proc activity which places the data you want to work with in a relevant table or storage account
2. call a notebook activity using the `spark.read.synapsesql` method as described in detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/synapse-spark-sql-pool-import-export?tabs=scala%2Cscala1%2Cscala2%2Cscala3%2Cscala4%2Cscala5).

The pattern:

[image]

Is there a particular reason you are copying existing data from the sql pool into Spark?  I do a very similar pattern but reserve it for things I can't already do in SQL, such as sophisticated transform, RegEx, hard maths, complex string manipulation etc

Comment: I am not copying data into spark again. I am trying to run my stored procedure created in ddsql pool in spark notebook. I didn't get the point 2 which u mentioned.

Comment: Don’t use Spark to run stored procedures, use the Stored Proc activity in a Synapse Pipeline.  Chain it together with a Notebook activity if you need to.